# toPrecision is adding up trailing zeros after the decimal point to total numbers intended

Tags: javascript, decimal, precision

After a long hour search, I'm asking this question.

I've a mission to restrict number to just 8 numbers in total. toPrecision is working as intended except this:

Some test cases:

1. 4828.39019785 -> 4828.3902 (intended)
2. 0.39019785 -> 0.39019785 (Although it returns total 9 digits, but it kinda work)
3. 0.0039019785 -> 0.0039019785 (Not intended, returning 11 digits)

It seems that toPrecision isn't working what it intended i.e to return the exact number we wanted. It adds up the zeros before the decimal and trailing zeros after the decimal into the total number of digits.

My intention:

2. 0.39019785 -> 0.3901978 (exactly 8 digits including 0)
3. 0.0039019785 -> 0.0039019 (exactly 8 digits including 3 zeros)

Comment: toFixed is for limiting numbers after decimal point. So for 1929.2816437221. It will return 1929.28164372 which is not intended as it returns 12 digits in total instead of 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var num1 = 0.39019785;
var num2 = 0.0039019785;

const exactPrecision = (number, precision) => number.toPrecision(precision).replace(new RegExp("((\\d\\.*){"+precision+"}).*"), '$1');

console.log(exactPrecision(num1, 8))
console.log(exactPrecision(num2, 8))
```

Hope that helps!

`toPrecision` doesn't do what you want when there're leading 0's so I created a function which gets rid of what's not needed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a while since he OP asked this question, but i came along a similar issue, so this is my proposal for a clean solution without any regex-magic:

```
function fiveDigits(x) {
    return x<1?x.toFixed(4):x.toPrecision(5);
}
```

In the case of leading zeroes, it will use `toFixed()` to limit the number of decimal places after the decimal separator. In case of bigger numbers without a 0 before the decimal separator, it rounds to the desired number of significant digits.

*Corner Case:* There is a caveat of course: In case you have large numbers that need more digits before the decimal separator, then the function yields a number string in exponential notation which of course eats up more characters.

```js
function fiveDigits(x) {
  return x<1?x.toFixed(4):x.toPrecision(5);
}

console.log(fiveDigits(123.456));
// expected output: "123.46"

console.log(fiveDigits(0.004));
// expected output: "0.0040"

console.log(fiveDigits(1.23e5));
// expected output: "1.2300e+5"
```

For me this solution works as intended and cleanly.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `toPrecision()` function. 
For example:

```js
console.log(Number(1).toPrecision(8));
```

This will give you `"1.0000000"`